# Include related fields in response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 8. I need to return the user as a response, with attached comments.

```
app.MapGet("data", async (MyBoardsContext db) =>
{
    var user = await db.Users
                       .Include(u => u.Comments)
                       .FirstAsync(user => user.Id == Guid.Parse("68366dbe-0809-490f-cc1d-08da10ab0e61"));
    
    return user;
});
```

In debugging mode, I can see that user has 8 attached comments, and that's fine, but in swagger/postman, the response is:

```
{
    "id": "68366dbe-0809-490f-cc1d-08da10ab0e61",
    "fullName": "Lola Hauck",
    "email": "Lola90@yahoo.com",
    "address": null
}
```

My User Entity:

```
namespace EntityApp.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id{get;set;}
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Address Address{get;set;}
        public List<WorkItem> WorkItems = new List<WorkItem>();
        public List<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>();
    }
}
```

Link to my repo which doesn't work:
https://github.com/Panda-313/.net-tutorial

Comment: Maybe you should look for returning the data as DTO (Data Transfer Object), instead of returning it as the entity model. With DTO, you add the properties that you want to be returned in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Include related fields in response
>
> I'm using Entity Framework - v8. I need to return the user as a
> response, with attached comments.

Well, based on your shared code snippet you should get commentList along with your userDto. But the [default serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization?view=net-8.0) might not include navigation properties which might cause null commnet. So you may need to configure it manually to handle related data.

However, according to your scenario, you should either return your [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) along with the comment class or alternatively you can enable [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-with-proxies).

But [using DTOs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) will certainly provide you more flexibility. Because for both User and Comment to represent the desired response structure.

Let's say, you have following  DTO:

```
public class UserWithCommentsDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

In this scenario, you could modify your code as following:

```
app.MapGet("data", async (MyBoardsContext db) =>
{
    var user = await db.Users
        .Include(u => u.Comments)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Id == Guid.Parse("68366dbe-0809-490f-cc1d-08da10ab0e61"));

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var userWithCommentsDTO = new UserWithCommentsDTO
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        FullName = user.FullName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Comments = user.Comments.ToList()
    };

    return userWithCommentsDTO;
});
```

**Note:** While creating the UserWithCommentsDto, I am  mappping user properties and then use Select to create CommentDto objects for each included comment, which, leads to the desired result set.

Output Sample:

[image]

Thus, according to your expectations, I think you are looking for this output. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) for additional example.